# Vagrant stencil-cli install

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

From a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.5 install, I configure the server as such:

(run `sudo apt-get update`)

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` (from nodejs docs)
2. `sudo apt-get install git -y`
3. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.28.0/install.sh | bash`
   `nvm install 4.1.2` (from stencil-cli docs page)
4. `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`

It returns this -

`npm WARN deprecated good-reporter@3.1.0: This module is no longer being maintained and is no longer needed for custom Good reporters.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency eslint-plugin-react@^4.2.3 included from eslint-config-airbnb will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
Killed`

Stopping before it is finished. What did I do wrong and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the virtual machine's memory was being maxed when launching the server. I increased the memory and the command stopped being halted.